# Tengo un error al momento de enviar datos por post con javascript

Tags: javascript, formularios, post

Para empezar tengo un archivo donde llamo a una consulta en mi base de datos mysql siempre y cuando se ingresen el código y la fecha.

```
        public function listarusuerfecha($fecha,$nombre) {
    try {
        $sql="select * from markers where nombre_usuario = :p_user AND fecha = :p_fech";

        //$sql = "select * from f_reporte_pedidos_clientes_ingresos(:p_fecha1, :p_fecha2, :p_tipo, :p_top, :p_tc)";
        $sentencia = $this->dblink->prepare($sql);
        $sentencia->bindParam(":p_user", $nombre);
        $sentencia->bindParam(":p_fech", $fecha);
        $sentencia->execute();
        $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $resultado;
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        throw $exc;
    }
}
```

Tengo otro archivo donde paso la variables por medio de post de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

  require_once '../negocio/MostrarMapa.clase.php';

  $fecha= $_POST["p_fecha"];
  $nombre= $_POST["p_nombre"];

   $objUsuario = new MostrarMapa();
try {
   $resultado = $objUsuario->listarusuerfecha($fecha,$nombre);
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
   header("HTTP/1.1 500");
   echo $exc->getMessage();
  }
 ?>
```

Cuando uso Postman me lista de forma correcta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de aquí viene mi problema he creado un formulario para enviar la fecha y el nombre del usuario de la siguiente forma:

```
  <form id="frmlistar">

            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Título de la ventana</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                <p>Código Cargo<input type="text" name="txtcodigousuario" id="txtcodigousuario" class="form-control input-sm text-center text-bold" placeholder="" readonly=""></p>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
              <p>Descripción <font color = "red">*</font>
                <input type="text" name="txtnombres" id="txtnombres" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" required=""><p>
                     </div>  
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                      <p>Fecha de Evento
                      <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtfechevent" name="txtfechevent" /></p>
                </div> 
                <div class="modal-footer">

        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value='Click' href='javascript:;' onclick="listar();" role="button">
          texto_boton &raquo;
        </a>
              </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
            </div>


        </form>
```

Por ultimo estoy tratando de enviar la fecha y el nombre del usuario por medio de javascript de la siguiente forma:

```
    function listar(){

    var nombre = document.getElementById("txtnombres").value;

    var fecha = document.getElementById("txtfechevent").value;
    $.post(
        "../controlador/ruta.controlador.php",
        {
            p_nombre : nombre,
            p_fecha : fecha
        }
        ).done(function(){                
          alert( "èxito" );

        }).fail(function(error){
            alert(error.responseText);
        });
```

};

Pero hasta ahora no he tenido los resultados esperados, alguien podría ayudarme por favor.

Comment: Hola, ¿Has probado quitando el espacio en blanco entre `p_nombre` y los dos puntos `:`? Deberías escribirlo así: `p_nombre: nombre`, lo mismo con el campo `p_fecha`.

Comment: Lo probé pero no me me funciona, pensé quizás estoy llamando mal desde javascript

Comment: ¿Qué significa exactamente "no me funciona"? ¿No se invoca el PHP? ¿Se invoca pero los parámetros no llegan? ¿Hay algún mensaje de error?

Comment: envió este alerta alert( "èxito" ); y todo bien hasta ahí parece que si es invocado desde el botón el problema es que cuando se ejecuta la función en javascript debería listarme los usuarios según nombre y fecha y no lo esta haciendo.